# Iterating on collection using asParallel vs async function()

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency, async-await, task-parallel-library

while trying to understand how to use parallelism and concurrency
i was comparing login on list that takes amount of time on three different methods while benchmarking these methods
but these three method got me very confused now:

> am asking what is going on with this code?

- **1st method is sync**
- **2nd mehtod is sync uses as parallel**
- **3rd mehtod is async uses normal loop with yeild**

```
public class LookUpCollections
    {

        private const int N = 3;
        private readonly List<int> _list;
        public LookUpCollections()
        {
            _list = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                _list.Add(i);
            }
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void ListLookup() => _list.ForEach(x => Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));

        [Benchmark]
        public void ListLookupAsParallel() => _list.AsParallel<int>().ForAll((x) =>  
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));

        [Benchmark]
        public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> ListLookupAsync()
        {
            foreach (var item in _list)
            {
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // the method will complete before 2sec delay 
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // some asynchronous work
                yield return item;
            }
        }

    }
```

here is the [benchmark results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaUV.png)

or here is the copy and past of the console in case something wrong with image:

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19041.450
.NET Core SDK=3.1.401
 [Host]    : .NET Core 2.1.21 
 DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.1.21
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
                Method                  Mean              Error             StdDev  
|--------------------- |--------------------:|-----------------:|-----------------:|
|           ListLookup | 6,027,116,440.00 ns | 6,926,407.532 ns | 6,478,965.903 ns |
| ListLookupAsParallel | 2,008,655,313.33 ns | 5,275,609.028 ns | 4,934,807.958 ns |
|      ListLookupAsync |            27.47 ns |         0.611 ns |         1.632 ns |                                                                                                          

  LookUpCollections.ListLookupAsync: Default -> 6 outliers were removed (37.39 ns..40.15 ns) 
// * Legends * 
Mean   : Arithmetic mean of all measurements
Error  : Half of 99.9% confidence interval
StdDev : Standard deviation of all measurements
1 ns   : 1 Nanosecond (0.000000001 sec)
```

Comment: Your question is "what is going on with this code"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias it looks to me that the OP is asking why there is such a difference between the three methods. Perhaps a question for one of the other StackOverflow sites?

Comment: @demonicdaron the OP has not made clear their expectations about these 3 methods. Did they expect that they'll all complete after 6 seconds? After 2 seconds? After zero seconds?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity ,but i don't know why the third method is the fastest ? ,i was expecting that it will complete after 2 seconds just like the second method

Comment: Read [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) which will provide you the details of async programming

Comment: And how exactly are you calling `ListLookupAsync`? If proper awaited it takes around 6 seconds to complete. For example by using  `await foreach(var i in ListLookupAsync()) { ... }`. If you do benchmark something make absolutely sure you are measuring the right thing.

Comment: Also, what makes you think the 3rd method will take 2 seconds? It will just sequentially await 2 seconds 3 times in a row. (The unawaited Task.Delay is ... well...pointless)

Comment: If the unexpected outcome is related to the third method, then IMHO including in the question the first and second methods is redundant and noisy. As it stands now, the generic question "what is going on with this code" invites an explanation for each one of the three methods, while it seems that you are interested only for an explanation of the third method. I suggest to edit your question and remove the first two methods, to make your question more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: @theodorZoulias your are a 100% right that i'm intereset in the last method as it seems better from the benchmark, even 2nd and the 3rd are doing the same delay() , why the last one didn't get even 2sec of execution

Comment: @PeterBons you totally make sense when it comes to the ```ListLookupAsync()``` but 6 seconds is never reached, even 2 , that why i'm lost when it comes to async

Comment: Please update your question with the code showing how the calls are made.

Comment: @user1672994 when i came across this link it actually made sense while reading, but when i was writing the third method i was expecting a behavior like in section "Await tasks efficiently" while adding delay to mimic some workload. even the article results was expected, the benchmark result wasn't

Comment: Sameh the role of the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) is neither to answer questions, nor to clarify questions. The questions should be self-sufficient, containing all the information needed to answer them. This is why I suggested to improve your question by removing the irrelevant parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your comments you have some questions about the result of the 3rd method. I've asked you how you call the method, because it does take ~6 seconds if called properly like this:

```cs
List<int> _list;

async Task Main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    
    _list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        _list.Add(i);
    }
    
    await foreach(var i in ListLookupAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);   
    }
}

public async IAsyncEnumerable<int> ListLookupAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Entering ListLookupAsync");
    
    foreach (var item in _list)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // some asynchronous work
        yield return item;
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Exiting ListLookupAsync");
}
```

I really suspect you are measuring the wrong thing. Basically consuming a `IAsyncEnumerable` kind of does have the same effect as consuming a non awaitable enumerable: iterations/yield returns are done **sequentially**. Since `_list` contains 3 items consuming the enumerable using the code above takes 3 times a two second delay.

If you want to execute *Task based methods* **in parallel** you could leverage `Task.WhenAll`:

```cs
List<int> _list;

async Task Main()
{
    const int N = 3;
    
    _list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        _list.Add(i);
    }
    
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - Before WhenAll");
    await Task.WhenAll(_list.Select(TaskBased));
    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} - After WhenAll");
}

public async Task TaskBased(int index)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); // some asynchronous work
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

This wil take ~2 seconds.

But please, no matter what: before questioning the results of a benchmark, make absolutely sure you understand what the code does otherwise you risk measuring the wrong thing and drawing wrong conclusions.

Comment: Yes you draw the big picture, as a rookie when it comes to this topic your answer is well understood, you talk about the method usage , IAsyncEnumerable , task based methods and testing the right thing , those hints are exactly what  i need to fill the gabs.